# LDAP query via IE search (provider)?

Tags: internet-explorer, search, internet-explorer-9, active-directory, ldap

I want to query our domain controller via LDAP for some user data like telephone number or mail address. Of course I can to this with different methods, but I would like to do this with a query in the search field of Internet Explorer 9. So is there a "search provider" or how would I have to define one for a LDAP query?
Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Thank you very much and excuse my limited english skills ;-)

Ruth

Answer (score 1):

A URL like ldap://host:port/dn?attributes?scope?filter?extensions should do it.

- host and port are obvious, except that ldap clear text runs over port
  389, SSL runs on 636, and with TLS can run on 389, issue a StartTLS
  and switch to encrypted while still on 389.  (Assume clear text for
  now).
- dn is the base to start searching from downwards.  For AD, this might
  be the dc=Doman,dc=com naming.  For eDirectory, OpenLDAP, or SunOne
  it is could be anything, but is more likely to be ou=domain,o=org or
  perhaps o=domain,dc=org or somesuch.
- attributes is a comma separated list of attributes you wish returned
  for any matching objects.
- scope is either subtree, entry, or one depending how deep you would
  like the search to go.
- filter is the key.  This is where you specify what you are looking
  for. Perhaps (uid=SomeuserName) or (mail=me@something.com) or
  (&(objectClass=User)(memberOf=Cn=groupA,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com))
  or the like.